# django custom field saves but not visualize

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-models

I created a Field to save the weekdays, used in a model like that (`models.py`):

```
from myfields import *
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    weekdays = WeekdayField()
```

The file in which i have stored the form declaration is `myfields.py` and is this one:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Weekdays(object):
    CHOICES = (
        (1, "Monday"),
        (2, "Tuesday"),
        (4, "Wednesday"),
        (8, "Thursday"),
        (16, "Friday"),
        (32, "Saturday"),
        (64, "Sunday"),
        )
    MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY = [2**i for i in range(0,7)]
    del i

    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.raw = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Weekdays(self.raw | other)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Weekdays(self.raw & (-1 ^ other))

    def __unicode__(self):
        ret = []
        for ele in Weekdays.CHOICES:
            if (self.raw & ele[0]) >> ele[0] == 1:
                ret.append(ele[1])
        return ",".join(ret)

    def __iter__(self):
        ret = []
        for ele in Weekdays.CHOICES:
            if (self.raw & ele[0]) >> ele[0] == 1:
                ret.append(ele)
        return iter(ret)

    def __len__(self):
        i = 0
        for n in range(7):
            if (self.raw & n) >> n == 1:
                i += 1
        return i



class WeekdayField(models.Field):
    description = "Multiple select of weekdays"

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 3
        super(WeekdayField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return [ wd for wd in Weekdays(value) ]
        if isinstance(value, Weekdays):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, list): #list of weekstay
            wd = Weekdays()
            for val in value:
                wd += int(val)
            return wd

    # PY to DB
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return value.raw

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': WeekdayFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(WeekdayField, self).formfield(**defaults)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "IntegerField"


class WeekdayFormField(forms.MultipleChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'choices' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['choices'] = Weekdays.CHOICES
        kwargs.pop('max_length', None)
        if 'widget' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['widget'] = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        super(WeekdayFormField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean(self, value):
        super(WeekdayFormField, self).clean(value)
        possible_values = [ str(x[0]) for x in Weekdays.CHOICES ]
        for v in value:
            if not v in possible_values:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Day not valid")
        return value
```

Using this i can create and remove the elements through Django Admin, but when i modify a value i don't see the value that i stored before. I looked into the database and the value are stored right.

Any ideas on how to make me see what is the current value on Django Admin, during the modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've the solution! it was a wrong the implementation of the methods `Weekdays.__unicode__()` and `Weekdays.__iter__()`.

Finally i had also changed the two methods reported below, in `WeekdayField`.

```
#Class-type
class Weekdays(object):
    ...

    def __unicode__(self): # Request for the matching
        ret = []
        for i,ele in enumerate(Weekdays.CHOICES):
            if (self.raw & ele[0]) >> i == 1:
                ret.append(unicode(ele[0]))
        return ','.join(ret)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i,ele in enumerate(Weekdays.CHOICES):
            if (self.raw & ele[0]) >> i == 1:
                yield Weekdays(ele[0])


#Field to include in the model
class WeekdayField(models.Field):
    ...

    # DB to PY
    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return [ wd for wd in Weekdays(value) ]
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            return [ wd for wd in Weekdays(int(value)) ]
        if isinstance(value, Weekdays):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, list): #list of Weekdays
            wd = []
            for val in value:
                wd += self.to_python(val)
            return wd

    #PY to DB
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Weekdays):
            return value.raw
        if isinstance(value, list):
            sum_raw = 0
            for val in value:
                sum_raw += self.get_prep_value(val)
            return sum_raw
```

I hope this will be helpful to someone!